# SQL Check if ungroup column values match

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I have a sql table with following values

```
       |  col1 | col2|   source |  values
       |  1    |  2  |  A       |   null
       |  1    |  2  |  B       |   1.0
       |  1    |  2  |  C       |   null
       |  1    |  4  |  A       |   2.0
       |  1    |  4  |  B       |   2.0
       |  1    |  4  |  C       |   2.0
       |  1    |  5  |  A       |   null
       |  1    |  5  |  B       |   null
       |  1    |  5  |  C       |   null
```

How can I get an output with a group by of `col1` and `col2` with a flag:

- all values match for a group ( flag = 1)
- all values are null ( flag = 2)
- some values is null (flag = 3)

Output:

```
       |  col1 | col2|   flag
       |  1    |  2  |   3
       |  1    |  4  |   1
       |  1    |  5  |   2
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: How this `flag` column should be evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>**Or:** based on your updated question:</strike>

```
  SELECT 
    col1, 
    col2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SomeConditionHere THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Flag
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7e12/8)

This will give  you:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | FLAG |
----------------------
|    1 |    2 |    2 |
|    1 |    4 |    0 |
|    1 |    5 |    3 |
```

**Note that:** I assumed that the flag is how many `NULL` values are in the `VALUES` column, so I used `"Values" IS NULL` instead of `SomeConditionHere`.

I couldn't understand how the `flag` should be computed in the expected results you posted. You have to use the predicate that define your flag instead of `"Values" IS NULL`.

### Update:

Try this:

```
WITH Flags
AS
(
  SELECT 
    col1, col2,
    COUNT(*) ValuesCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN "Values" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NULLValues
  FROM Table1 
  GROUP BY col1, col2
)
SELECT 
  col1,
  col2,
  Flag = CASE WHEN ValuesCount = NULLValues THEN 2
              WHEN NULLVALUES = 0 
               AND ValuesCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                  FROM Table1 t2
                                  WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1
                                    AND t1.col2 = t2.col2) THEN 1
               ELSE 3
END
FROM Flags t1;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7e12/33)

This will give you:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | FLAG |
----------------------
|    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |    1 |
|    1 |    5 |    2 |
```

Comment: thanks for this. By flag i mean if all values match for a group ( flag = 1), if all values are null ( flag = 2), if any values is null (flag = 3) thanks again

Comment: @mushtaqck OK, Sorry I missed this out. So this is for the values in the `values` column only not the `score` column? right?

Answer (score 3):

In SQLServer2005+

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT col1, col2, [values],       
         COUNT(CASE WHEN [values] IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2) AS cntNULL,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2) AS cntCol
  FROM dbo.test5
  )
  SELECT col1, col2, MAX(CASE WHEN cntNULL = 0 THEN 1
                              WHEN cntNULL = cntCol THEN 2
                              ELSE 3 END) AS flag
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f90e/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

...And solution without CTE if you want more portable `SQL`:

```
select col1,
       col2,
        case 
            when DistinctValuesWithoutNulls = 1 and NullCount = 0 then 1 
            when DistinctValuesWithoutNulls = 0 then 2
            when NullCount > 0 then 3
        end flag
from
(
    select  col1, 
            col2, 
            count(distinct [values]) DistinctValuesWithoutNulls, 
            sum(case when [values] is null then 1 else 0 end) NullCount
    from Table1
    group by col1, col2
) tmp
```